# stem and leaf plot

Tags: r, self-study

1.) Read this stem and leaf plot, enter in the data and make a histogram
-> So I have to enter in the data in a stem and leaf plot.
This is the code I used to do but when I did it gave me a different result.

My solution:

```
> x <- c(8028, 9115578, 101669, 1101)

> stem(x, scale=1)
```

(This is what appeared on the R Console)
  The decimal point is 6 digit(s) to the right of the |

```
0 | 001

2 | 

  4 | 

  6 | 

  8 | 1
```

[image: This is the following result I need to display]

So does anybody know how to display exactly like the image given? Thanks :)

Comment: This seems like homework. You should add the tag self-study.

Answer (score 1):

I don't mean to be rude, but you don't seem to have read about how to interpret stem leaf diagrams. The first line of the stem diagram is interpreted as the values 80, 82 and 88. The next one as 91, 91, 95... etc. So now I think you might figure out the rest of the values by yourself. They then want you to construct a histogram which can be done with the hist() command in R.